# getenv() does not find the environment variable that I manually set(I am writing in C)

Tags: c, windows, environment-variables

If I try to get one of the existing variables everything works but if i try to access my variable the method returns NULL.I am writing this under windows 10 :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    test1();
    return 0;
}

int test1()
{
    char *libvar = getenv("NS_RULEBASE_PATH");

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("D:/debug.txt", "w+");

    if (libvar) {
        fprintf(fp, libvar);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(fp, "env not set");
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the question instead of linking to a screenshot ...

Comment: Also, how did you set the environment variable? If you used `set` in `cmd`, then it only applies to the current process. If you used the GUI for setting environment variables, then you need to restart applications that should be aware of the changed variables.

Comment: Be aware that `fprintf(fp, libvar)` is a little dangerous if you don't know what's in that string.  A safer way to do this is `fprintf(fp, "%s", libvar)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx) says:

> getenv():  The return value is NULL if varname is not found in the
>   environment table.

On my computer,

```
char *libvar = getenv("USERNAME");
std::cout << libvar << std::endl;
```

prints my username. You can see if your environment variable is set via a command prompt by typing `echo %NS_RULEBASE_PATH%`, to see if it print the value of %NS_RULEBASE_PATH%.

**Edit:** as the doc says :

> getenv operates only on the data structures accessible to the run-time library and not on the environment "segment" created for the process by the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) it turns out that the variable wasn't set correctly after i set it again everything worked

Comment: Happy to help @Givko , and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.